# How can I create an alias synonym?

Tags: bash, alias

I have an alias `pwd`

How can I create another alias that is a synonym for it?

For example I have

```
alias cd1='cd ~/dir1'
```

I want a second alias `cd01` that points to the same place but I don't want to also have:
`alias cd01='cd ~/dir1'`
in case `/dir1` changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works in both bash and zsh.

```
$ alias cd1='cd /'
$ alias cd01=cd1
$ cd01; pwd
/
# now, to change cd1
$ alias cd1='cd /etc'
$ cd01; pwd
/etc
```

Answer (score 1):

It should works. On my systems, I have:

```
alias ls='ls -F'
alias ll='ls -l'
```

That means ll is alias to `ls -F -l`. Have you tried your scenario out?